# How to generate a covariance matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, covariance

So I would like to generate a $50\times50$ covariance matrix for a random variable $X \in \mathbb{R}^{50}$ given the following conditions:

1. one variance is 10 times larger than the others
2. The parameters of $X$ are only slightly correlated

Is there a way of doing this in Python/R etc? Or is there a covariance matrix that you can think of that might satisfy these requirements?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Numbers ($>0$) along the principal diag are variances. Make one of them larger than the rest, as req'd. $Cov(X_i, X_j) = \sigma_{ij}= Cov(X_j, X_i) = \sigma_{ji},$ for $i \ne j$ account for the other entries. Not just any choices will do. In gen'l, they _could_ all be $0,$ but you want 'slight' correlation. Please investigate the rules. Then you can make your own matrix. // Strictly speaking, I think you mean something other than "parameters." (Parameters may _indicate_ correlation, but they are numbers and cannot _be_ correlated. // Just an exercise, or do you have an application in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Comment continued:** I don't know if this is of any help, but you mentioned R in your Question. Here is an R
program that generates fake data and then finds the *sample* variance-covariance
matrix.

I use $5$ instead of $50$ variables to save space, but the idea is the same. At the start, the respective *population* variances of the five
variables are $10, 1, 1, 1,$ and $1,$ and the sample variances (for $n = 10,000$ observations per variable) are nearly the
same.

The same `noise` vector with very small variance is added to each of the variables, thus simulating small (mainly positive) sample correlations among the variables. (Of course, this adds a little to the population variances of the variables.)

The resulting variance-covariance matrix may give you an idea
what you need to do.

```
set.seed(1234)  # set a different seed for a fresh simulation
n = 10^4
X = matrix(0, ncol=5, nrow=n)
noise = rnorm(n, 0, .01)    
X[,1] = rnorm(n, 0, sqrt(10)) + noise
for(i in 2:5){
  X[,i] = rnorm(n, 0, 1) + noise }
var(X)
##             [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]         [,5] 
##[1,] 10.120852001 -0.003395094  0.032612955 -0.066317355 -0.017420682
##[2,] -0.003395094  0.998067921  0.002402681 -0.013012347  0.031856352
##[3,]  0.032612955  0.002402681  1.009511299 -0.001593524  0.001492451
##[4,] -0.066317355 -0.013012347 -0.001593524  1.009853838  0.024616714
##[5,] -0.017420682  0.031856352  0.001492451  0.024616714  0.988864284
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! It is extremely helpful!

Comment: I don't know if you're supposed to make a sample cov matrix or a pop cov matrix. If pop, you can view $X = Y + Z$ where $Y ~ Norm(0,\sigma=\sqrt{10})$ or $Norm(0,1)$ and Z is noise. $Var(X)=Var(Y)+Var(Z).$ $Cov(X_2, X_3) = Var(Z).$ Etc.